# Force QMenu to close

Tags: c++, qt, qdialog, qmenu, qaction

Due to some reasons I need to implement specific menu in QToolBar. My target is to save the default design of a button with drop-down menu (icon + triangle), but I want to show my own QDialog (it looks like a tree) when I press this triangle.

So, now I have something like this:

```
class CustomMenu : public QMenu
{
  Q_OBJECT;

public:

  CustomMenu(QWidget *parent);

signals:
  void showMyMenu();
};
```

This is how I create this menu and connects it with needed slots:

```
CustomMenu *menu = new CustomMenu(tb);         
connect(menu, SIGNAL(aboutToShow()), menu, SIGNAL(showMyMenu()));
connect(menu, SIGNAL(showMyMenu()), this, SLOT(execMyMenu()));       
tbButton->setMenu(menu);
tb->addAction(tbButton);
```

Here's the slot:

```
void MyProjectClass::execMyMenu()
{

  CustomMenu *cm = (CustomMenu*)sender();

  CustomMenuWidget* myMenu = new CustomMenuWidget();        
  myMenu->exec();

  cm->hide();

  delete myMenu;
}
```

The problem here is that calling `hide()` for `CustomMenu` doesn't make triangle become unpressed and it still holds a focus on the button. That makes impossible to click something else until you don't get rid of the focus from that button.

Everything I want is to substitute default drop-down menu with my custom one.

It seems to be very easy, but I probably missed something. What am I doing wrong?

 I'm using ***Qt 4.8.6***

Comment: is there any way to programmatically tell QMenu to close, because `close()` and `hide()` doesn't do that?

Comment: You can change a focus after destroying a menu

Comment: @SaZ how can I do it?

Comment: @SaZ actually, I'm not pretty sure about connecting to `aboutToShow()`  signal, but I didn't find the way to reimplement how default menu appears. I've tried to reimplement `show()`, `exec()`, `popup()` but none of them are called when the default menu appears on the screen.

Comment: I misunderstood something. Why do you need to inherit `QMenu`?

Comment: If you need a custom content inside any menu you may use `QWidgetAction` class

Comment: @SaZ the problem is quiet different: I have specific QDialog which I need to show when I press on QAction in toolbar. This dialog contents specific presentation of data and I can't change it. I have already tried to do this with `QWidgetAction`, but this didn't help. Now, I'm trying to cheat with `QMenu` by catching its signal before opening to show my dialog. Everything works great, but when I press 'apply' button which causes dialog to close I can't force `QMenu` to close and the small down-arrow on the right side remains pressed. That's why I'm asking about way to close it programmatically